# django rest framework return file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view in my views.py -

```
class FilterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = cdx_composites_csv

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        vendor = self.request.GET.get('vendor')
        filename = self.request.GET.get('filename')
        tablename = filename.replace(".","_")
        model = get_model(vendor, tablename)
        filedate = self.request.GET.get('filedate')        
        snippets = model.objects.using('markitdb').filter(Date__contains=filedate)
        serializer = cdx_compositesSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        if format == 'raw':
            zip_file = open('C:\temp\core\files\CDX_COMPOSITES_20140626.zip', 'rb')
            response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/force-download')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % 'CDX_COMPOSITES_20140626.zip'
            return response

        else:
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

It works great for xml, json, csv but when I try to use raw it's not returning the file instead it's giving ""detail": "Not found"" why is this happening?

The URL I'm hitting is as follows -

json example that works -

`http://dt-rpittom:8000/testfilter/?vendor=markit&filename=cdx_composites.csv&filedate=2014-06-26&format=json`

This should return a zip file for download.

`http://dt-rpittom:8000/testfilter/?vendor=markit&filename=cdx_composites.csv&filedate=2014-06-26&format=raw`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know why I had to do this - may be something internal to Django Rest Framework that doesn't allow putting custom methods onto format?

I simply changed it to the following -

```
if fileformat == 'raw':
    zip_file = open('C:\temp\core\files\CDX_COMPOSITES_20140626.zip', 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(zip_file), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % 'CDX_COMPOSITES_20140626.zip'
    return response
```

Then in my URL just hit with the new value and it works fine.  I'd love to know why I can't use format though to serve a file.

Comment: The format is used to determine which renderer to use. Since raw does not have any renderer associated with it, which is used by this view, it returns a not found error.

Answer (score 13):

Try using `FileWrapper`:

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper

...

if format == 'raw':
    zip_file = open('C:\temp\core\files\CDX_COMPOSITES_20140626.zip', 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(zip_file), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % 'CDX_COMPOSITES_20140626.zip'
    return response
...
```

Also, I would use [`application/zip`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/zip) instead of `application/force-download`.

Comment: This still has the same problem.  it returns the django rest framework http page and the content is ""detail": "Not found""

Comment: Django 1.10 here: using `django.core.files.File` instead of `FileWrapper` works for me.