# How do I use django rest framework to send a file in response?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I need to send a pdf file and some other parameters in response to a get API call using django rest framework.

How can I do it?
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449946/django-rest-framework-return-file) but it gives an error `<django.http.HttpResponse object at 0x7f7d32ffafd0> is not JSON serializable`.

```
@detail_route(methods=['get'])
def fetch_report(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    short_report = open("somePdfFile", 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(short_report), content_type='application/pdf')
    return Response({'detail': 'this works',
        'report': response})
```

Comment: You cannot do this in one step. Either the answer is PDF, or the answer is JSON. You could encode the content of the pdf into a JSON string, but it will be (doable but) hard to get it to save on the client. Usually this kind of stuff is done in a 2-step process: first get the JSON answer, then, if it succeeded, request the actual file.

Answer (score 20):

The problem here is that you are trying to return a mix of JSON and PDF, which either isn't what you are looking for or is going to return a *giant* base64-encoded response. PDF is a binary format and JSON is a text format, and you can't really mix them well.

Within a DRF view you can directly return a Django response, which you already appear to be generating (the `HttpResponse`), and DRF will pass it through and skip the renderers. This is useful in cases like this, as it allows you to return a binary response such as an image or PDF without worrying about DRF's rendering layer causing problems.

```
@detail_route(methods=['get'])
def fetch_report(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    short_report = open("somePdfFile", 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(short_report), content_type='application/pdf')
    return response
```

The alternative is to encode the PDF as text, using something like [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). This will dramatically increase your response sizes, but it will allow you to use DRF's rendering layer without problems.

```
@detail_route(methods=['get'])
def fetch_report(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    import base64
    short_report = open("somePdfFile", 'rb')
    report_encoded = base64.b64encode(short_report.read())
    return Response({'detail': 'this works',
        'report': report_encoded})
```

But the route I would recommend here is to generate the PDF and store it in either your media storage, or an alternative private location, and provide a direct link to it in your response. This way you don't need to worry about the encoding issues, don't need to directly return the PDF, and don't need to worry about directly serving the PDF.

Answer (score 16):

If you really need to serve binary files directly from your backend (e.g. when they're being generated dynamically) you can use a custom [renderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers):

```
from rest_framework.renderers import BaseRenderer

class BinaryFileRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    format = None
    charset = None
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data
```

Then use it in your action in a viewset:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action

@action(detail=True, methods=['get'], renderer_classes=(BinaryFileRenderer,))
def download(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    with open('/path/to/file.pdf', 'rb') as report:
        return Response(
            report.read(),
            headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'},
            content_type='application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[DRF-PDF](https://github.com/drgarcia1986/drf-pdf)** project with *PDFFileResponse*:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from drf_pdf.response import PDFFileResponse
from drf_pdf.renderer import PDFRenderer


class PDFHandler(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (PDFRenderer, )

    def get(self, request):
        return PDFFileResponse(
            file_path='/path/to/file.pdf',
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

But, maybe you cannot respond in both formats (json and stream).

Answer (score 2):

With DRF you can write as following:

```
    pdf_file_in_bytes = AnyModel.file.read()  # file is a FileField
    pdf_file_name = "PDF's Download Name"
    response = Response(
        headers={'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename={pdf_file_name}'},
        content_type='application/pdf'
    )
    response.content = pdf_file_in_bytes
    return response
```

Comment: I find this the best approach since it uses the `rest_framework.response.Response` object and need no dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can send pdf file as a response to any request without installing any packages.

You can do the following.

```
def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # some code
    # some code

    with fs.open("path/to/file/Report.pdf") as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Report.pdf"
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)

        return response
```

Now, open your `postman` and hit a `get/post` request.

**Important:** Before clicking `send` button in postman, select the option `send and download`.

Comment: This works perfectly if you want to download a document. Tnx man.