# How to view API data within a GET method that's created using POST method in Django (without a model)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created a DRF API that allows me to submit an image using the POST method via POSTMAN. The image is not stored in the model. After it's submission, I want to view the image's name in the browser using the Django Rest Framework. After reading sources in the net, I found out that people used the GET method in order to view all the data in a model. However, I don't have a model (don't require it for now) so how can I implement this requirement?

The result should be something like this:

```
{
    "image_name": <"name_of_the_image_stored">
}
```

This is what I had done so far:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from .serializers import ImgSerializer
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser

class ImageAPI(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
    def post(self, request):
        #key is 'image' when uploading in POSTMAN
        file = self.request.data
        data = file['image']
        if data:
            uploaded_file = data
            fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT)
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            data = [{"image_name": filename}]  
            serializer = ImgSerializer(data, many = True).data
            return Response(serializer, status = 200)               
        else:
            return Response("Please upload an image", status = 400)

    def get(self, request):
         #What should I do here in order to view the submitted image above?
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ImgSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    image_name = serializers.CharField()
```

urls.py:

```
from upload.views import ImageAPI
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/", ImageAPI.as_view(), name = "api"),
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Comment: If you don't have a model, how do you save the image_name?

Comment: I saved it in my directory. Apart from this, I used a serializer to store the image_name data. I don't intend to use a model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `parser_classes` should be an attribute of `ImageAPI` class, as I can see you've created it as a local variable, which won't do what you want. According to [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser) the `request.data` property should be a dictionary with a single key `file` containing the uploaded file. And regarding viewing the saved image, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438729/how-do-i-use-django-rest-framework-to-send-a-file-in-response) you can find some ways to do that.

This is an example:

```
...
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # here I assume you've sent the name of the image using query params, 
    # but there are other better ways to do that
    image_name = request.GET.get('image')

    # here you should read the file from your storage
    image_file = <read_image_file_by_given_name(image_name)>

    return HttpResponse(image_file, content_type='image/png')
```

Comment: I made the changes accordingly as you mentioned above. But I still don't understand how to view the name of the image using the GET method. Can you demonstrate a simple example, please?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not pass the name of the image in the query params. What is wrong with your current method though? Also, I will be saving the image in a server later, if I want to view the image in the API browser, what's the best way to retrieve the image apart from using the os module?

Comment: This is just a plan, which can help you to implement what you want.

Comment: How can you read the file from the POST method instead of the storage? I don't want to access the storage in order to fetch the filename. Is it possible to save data using serializers in the POST method and call the serializer in the GET method in order to view the data?