# Django rest framework ApiView reurn executable file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Question similar to this
[django rest framework return file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449946/django-rest-framework-return-file)

Trying to apply a similar solution to return an executable python binary in Django Rest `ApiView`:

```
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

bin_file = open(f'cli/builds/dist/cli', 'rb')
response = Response(FileWrapper(bin_file), content_type='application/octet-stream')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="cli"'
response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
return response
```

getting `Object of type 'FileWrapper' is not JSON serializable` error.
Referring to the previously mentioned SO topic - this solution is warking for a zip file.

**Question** - why doesn't it work for my setting, returning the python executable?

`python 3.6.5`,
`djangorestframework==3.8.2`

tried both `Response` and `HttpResponse` classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **`HttpResponse`** instead of DRF's **`Response`**,

```
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

bin_file = open(f'cli/builds/dist/cli', 'rb')
response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(bin_file), content_type='application/octet-stream')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="cli"'
response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
return response
```

Comment: You won't get `Object of type 'FileWrapper' is not JSON serializable` error if you are using **`HttpResponse`**. (I tried this solution myself, and works perfectly)

Comment: Hey, thanks, i got it. I was using `HttpResponse` from `django.http` instead of from `django.http.response`. Seems like they are different. Typical blind mistake :D

Comment: Happy coding :)