# How to solve TypeError: Object of type HttpResponse is not JSON serializable?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pickle, httpresponse

I am trying to return a model.pkl file using postman from an API made in django rest framework. However the response I get is `TypeError: Object of type HttpResponse is not JSON serializable`.

The following code is what I am using to return the file, but I cannot understand what is going wrong (this was inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449946/django-rest-framework-return-file)).

```py
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK
import pickle
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

# views.py
...
model_pickle_path = f'/path/model_state.pkl'
#model_pickle_trained = pickle.load(open(model_pickle_path, 'rb'))
model_pickle_trained = open(model_pickle_path, 'rb')

response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(model_pickle_trained), content_type='application/octet-stream')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % model_filename_defined
return Response(data=response, status=HTTP_200_OK)

Traceback:
TypeError: Object of type HttpResponse is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: `HttpResponse` was used as the data for `Response`? To fix this you can just do `return response`

Comment: @BrianDestura this really solve the issue. Thanks for the response. Why `Response` was being an issue?

Comment: Hint: ```Response(HttpResponse())```, this is what you did!

Comment: @Sumithran thank you for the clarification